# How to prove that a two-photon transition amplitude is absent in a crystal that obeys inversion symmetry?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter

In crystals that obey inversion symmetry retain their polarization form in $x\to -x$, we can prove that even order susceptibilities get canceled. But I want to know if there exists any way that I can explicitly show that even order transition amplitudes are not contributing to the higher-order harmonic generation in these particular crystals.